# Running Sudoku Solver Example in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run sudoku solver provided with hadoop example jar file. I am not sure the format in which input is supposed to be given. Can anybody guide?

Thanks,
Tapan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/dancing/package-summary.html):

> The sudoku solver is so fast, I didn't bother making a distributed
>   version. (All of the puzzles that I've tried, including a 42x42 have
>   taken around a second to solve.) On the command line, give the solver
>   a list of puzzle files to solve. **Puzzle files have a line per a row
>   and columns separated by spaces. The squares either have numbers or
>   '?' to mean unknown.**

Comment: Thanks! I was able to run the sudoku solver program. However, I realized that it requires the input puzzle to be present on local file system and not on hdfs. It is quite un-natural of map-reduce programs on hadoop. Generally, they expect the input to reside on hdfs file system.
I ran my program as:

hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.203.0/hadoop-examples-0.20.203.0.jar sudoku sudoku_in.txt

where sudoku_in.txt was in current working directory in unix system.